# How to enable editing of google script code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

When I open the google script editor from a Google form, I see no code and can't edit the code.I only see 5 empty lines. Can it be related to a problem with installation of Javascript on my computer?

Comment: A screen shot of what you can see would help. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204546/using-an-imported-module-inside-google-app-script) the GAS 'JavaScript' environment is server based So your code does not have a local browser/JavaScript dependency; but if I disable JS in the browser the actual GAS editor gives me the following error: "JavaScript isn't enabled in your browser, so this file can't be opened. Enable and reload."; so the editor does need it. What happens if you access  https://script.google.com/home? Can you see, create any standalone GAS projects?

Comment: I was able to work around the problem by changing the user default language to English. Maybe the Chrome browser opens a page for editing code which attempts to edit in the default Google user language, and fails when it is not English.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be related a problem with installation of JavaScript on your computer as Google Apps Script doesn't require anything but a supported web browser.

It could be a problem of the cookies, the cache or an browser plugin or extension that is interfering.

Check that you are using a supported web browser and it's updated. If the problem persist try in incognito/safe mode with all the extensions disabled.