# Supabase and Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, supabase, supabase-database

Is it possible to use Supabase with Google Apps Script (GAS)?

I'm new to Supabase and I've never tried to import external library to GAS before. I'm planning to use Supabase as a database for my project in GAS. The project is built to run a bot in a chatting platform rather than a user interface. Based on the [documentation from Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/installing), it looks like it works by executing function from the Supabase library.

I have tried to use the Supabase library by copy-pasting the whole library from [here](https://unpkg.com/@supabase/supabase-js) or using `eval()`, but all of them return the error: `ReferenceError: self is not defined`.

Here is the function I run that uses `eval()`:

```
function myFunction(){
  var x = eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://unpkg.com/@supabase/supabase-js").getContentText())
  var supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl,supabaseKey)
}
```

`createClient()` is supposed to be a function from the Supabase library.

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support the import and export statements apparently required by the linked library. Please add more details about what supabase features are looking to use on Google Apps Script an a brief description of how you will use them. Better if you include a [mcve].

Comment: Possible related https://stackoverflow.com/q/49204546/1595451

Comment: @Rubén thank you, I've updated some information on the post based on what I've tried

Comment: IMHO there isn't enough details yet.

Comment: Have you tried creating a web app and use the JS from the <script> tag inside the HTML: [HTML Service: Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)

Comment: @Kessy I've never tried using .html before because I don't build a user interface. My project is built to run a bot (I'll update this info on the post). Care to give me some guidance?

Comment: The html is to be able to call the library. Also note that to call the library is not correct on your side, it should be `libraryName.method`. You can also create another .gs file with the library functions and import it to your main project as a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible route that I can think of to make this work is to use [Postgrest](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/index.html), which is the underlining API server that Supabase users.

Since every Supabase instance can be accessed using rest API provided by Postgrest, you should be able to perform insert, update, delete and read operations to your Supabase database from your GAS project.

You can probably run something like this to access Supabase.

```
$anonKey = "YOUR_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY_HERE"
$url = "YOUR_SUPABASE_URL_HERE"
$var options = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "Authorization" : "Bearer " + $anonKey,
       "apikey": $anonKey
     }
   };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch($url + "YOUR_QUERY_PARAMETER_FOR_POSTGREST", options);
```