Is there a way to rotate an image certain degrees in google sheet from the google apps script?
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id...");
const sheett1 = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1'), true)
images = sheett1.getImages();
var lastImage = images[images.length - 1];
lastImage.setWidth(100);
lastImage.setHeight(100);

// Now i need to rotate the image 45 degrees, please help, i already tried to use these methods but it seems they are not available, does anyone know any way to rotate the image from google script apps?
lastImage.rotate(45);       //! Error TypeError: lastImage.rotate is not a function
lastImage.setRotate(45);    //! Error TypeError: lastImage.setRotate is not a function 


Is the image from a url link?

yes sir -El maestro-, first I add the images from the DriveApp, the question is that I need that at the moment of inserting them they are with specific dimensions (width height) and rotation (30°, 45°,...)

It is that I must always specify first the dimensions and then rotate them so that the proportions in the image are not lost with respect to the established measures. If this is not possible, I would have to generate an equation that calculates the proportions with the height and width of the rotated image.

If you have any ideas, please share them with me, maybe I can solve my question, thank you very much.

It's not easy to do this. The way I'll try to do this is(with no guarantee of success): First I'll download the image using UrlFetchApp get the data as Blob and getBytes() from the Blob to get the raw data. Once that is achieved, I'll try to implement some nodejs compatible image manipulation library inside apps script using rollup or webpack(This may require lot of work, if something is incompatible in apps script environment https://stackoverflow.com/q/49204546) Once that's done, we try to rotate the image using the library and get back the image and set it back to ss.
